# Why can't I create a closure in nodejs a module

Tags: node.js, module, requirejs

I'm trying to make the following nodejs module:

```
exports.method = function () {      
  var init = true;

  return function (args) {
     console.dir(args);
  };
};
```

But when I invoke this method I don't get console message:

```
require('./module.js').method({test: 1});
```

It returns a function instead of invoking it.

Comment: It does exactly what you're asking to do. What do you want it to do?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need to execute the outer function, otherwise you're simply assigning it to `exports.method`.

In other words:

```
exports.method = function () {      
  var init = true;

  return function (args) {
     console.dir(args);
  };
}();
```

Note the trailing `()`

Comment: They basically impact memory the way you would expect. A closure keeps references to memory in a scope that might otherwise be destroyed. But if you need access to that scope, then it's a perfectly reasonable use of memory. JavaScript makes extensive use of closures; it's a semi-functional language.